# how to copy files on windows host from linux host

Tags: linux, telnet

here is a window host ip is 192.168.8.1

i can telnet in this host from linux host 192.168.2.1 and name/pwd is test test

i want a shell script to login in window host(192.168.8.1),and copy d:/log to f:/log.

from linux host ,how to write this linux script .

I hava already tried to think,thank you for you to answer it.

Comment: See if you can use `rlogin`, if so you can, then you can execute commands with `rsh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install an ssh server on windows (for example  OpenSSH)

Here a link of a tutorial: http://www.worldgoneweb.com/2011/installing-openssh-on-windows-7/

Then you can use the `scp` command from linux machine to copy your files. http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

Answer (score 1):

I would first ask if you have any other access to the windows host? Does it have a ftp server? 
Is it or can it share drives? Assuming you need to transfer the file via the telnet session stream you can check out Kermit. It was originally written to work on serial lines, but can also work with telnet sessions. A version of kermit needs to be installed on both windows and linux. It works with binary files. It also changes line endings if needed. Another possibility is zmodem.
Old versions of kermit are public domain. Should be Ok. Newer versions are not. See http://www.omen.com/zmdmev.html